# Bedeutet dieser Abschnitt "unter dem sprichwörtlichen Kopfkissen ruhen lassen" "das Geld sparen"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom

> Man kann Geld neben den bereits erwähnten Funktionen auch behalten. Es ist also nicht immer notwendig, es sofort auszugeben. Nein. Man kann es im Portemonnaie oder **unter dem sprichwörtlichen Kopfkissen ruhen lassen** oder an Dritte verleihen und dafür Zinsen verlangen.

Danach suche ich im Duden, Dwds, linguee und Googleübersetzung aber finde nichts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bedeutet dieser Abschnitt “unter dem sprichwörtlichen Kopfkissen ruhen lassen” “das Geld sparen”?

**Das ist richtig, das bedeutet es. So ist es gemeint!**

(Man kann es aber auch wie meine Schwiegermutter im Keller zwischen den Confiture-Gläsern verstecken. Sie hatte zwar nicht viel, aber dort wurde es ihr weder von den Banken noch von Einbrechern gestohlen.)

Im Duden steht leider nichts darüber ... dafür aber hier:

https://www.dwds.de/wb/sparen

**"sparen Vb. ‘nicht völlig aufbrauchen, Geld nicht (völlig) ausgeben’, ahd. sparōn (8. Jh., vorwiegend frk.), sparēn (9. Jh., vorwiegend obd.), mhd. sparn ‘(ver)schonen, bewahren, beschützen, aufschieben, unterlassen’,** asächs. sparon, mnd. spāren, sparren, mnl. spāren, nl. sparen, afries. sparia, aengl. sparian, engl. to spare, anord. schwed. spara (germ. *sparēn, *sparōn) ist abgeleitet von dem in ahd. spar ‘sparsam, knapp’ (10. Jh.), mnl. spaer, aengl."

Klar wird hier nicht wörtlich gesagt, unter dem Kopfkissen aufbewahren. Aber es gibt immer wieder Zeitungsmeldungen, dass jemand das Geld unter der Matratze aufbewahrt hat um es zu sparen, was in etwa dasselbe ist wie: **unter dem Kopfkissen ruhen lassen.**

Viele Leute, die in den letzten Jahre ihr Geld in Aktien angelegt haben, wären heute  froh, sie hätten es gespart, indem sie es unter dem Kopfkissen hätten ruhen lassen. Und das ist wörtlich gemeint.

Und andere die ihr Geld gegen Zinsen ausgeliehen haben - an Freunde oder Institutionelle - um es dort mit Gewinn "arbeiten" lassen, habe oftmals nichts gesehen, weder die Zinsen noch das Geld.

Comment: weshalb downvote? Ich habe doch schön eine Begründung abgegeben, wie es sich gehört. Ist hier etwa ein Banker anwesend, der uns weis machen will, dass nur auf einem Bankkonto gespart werden kann?

Comment: Ich denke, es geht hier nicht um die Frage, ob es gut oder schlecht ist, das Geld unter dem Kopfkissen zu sparen. Es stimmt, dass man das Geld spart, wenn man es unter das Kopfkissen legt. Allerdings wird nicht die ganze Bedeutung von "unter dem Kopfkissen ruhen lassen" erfasst, wenn man es einfach mit sparen übersetzt.

Comment: Nur eine Vermutung (der dv ist nicht von mir): Weil sich die lange Antwort wie eine Anekdote liest und viel davon für die Beantwortung der Frage unerheblich ist (das ganze Zitat inkl. etymologischer Herleitung). Du sagst »ja«, und der ganze Rest hat wenig **konkret** mit der Frage zu tun.

Answer (score 1):

"Sparen" bedeutet Aufbewahrung von Geld gegen Zinsen. "Unter dem Kopfkissen lagern" bedeutet Aufbewahrung *ohne* Zinsen. Das war einmal ein erheblicher Unterschied, aber in der jetzigen Niedrigzinsphase sind beide Optionen fast gleichwertig.

Comment: Dass "sparen" nur mit im Zusammenhang mit Banken und Sparkassen zu verstehen wird, ist eine Behauptung, die erst begründet werden müsste. Hingegen hast du recht, dass man heute gescheiter das Geld unter dem Kopfkissen ruhen lässt als zu der Bank trägt. Da bezahlst du sogar Strafzinsen, wenn du reich genug bist.
https://www.dwds.de/wb/sparen

Comment: In der süddeutsch-ländlichen Welt, aus der ich komme, versteht man, wenn man "sparen" hört, dass man Geld nicht ausgibt sondern für spätere Nutzung aufbewahrt. Wo man es lagert (Bank, Kopfkissen, Marmeladenglas) und ob es beim Lagern mehr wird (Zinsen) spielt bei der Wortwahl keine Rolle.

Comment: @Christian, Menschen habe schon gespart, bevor es Banken gab, zum Glück, sonst hätte sie im Winter nichts zu Essen gehabt.

Comment: @Takkat Kommentare zu löschen weil Sie dieser Antwort widersprechen würden, vorgeblich weil Kommentare nicht für Diskussionen gedacht sind, ist nicht gerade die Feine Art.

Comment: @vectory: **es wurden gar keine Kommentare zu dieser Antwort gelöscht!** Abgesehen davon, [mach dich bitte hiermit vertraut](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Hier ist der [Meta-Post](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1407/please-do-not-answer-a-question-in-a-comment) bezüglich des Löschens solcher Kommentare.

Answer (score 1):

Unter dem Kopfkissen verstaut kann etwas nur schwer gestohlen werden, ohne den Besitzer zu wecken. Das sinnbildliche Verstauen eines Wertgegenstands unter der Matratze ist eher transparent und bedeutet

> Geld sichern

Angesichts "be-sitzen" dürften vergleichbare Sinnbilder beträchtliches Alter aufweisen.

Daher folgen ein paar Gedanken zur Herleitung:

Man sagt auch, sich auf etwas *ausruhen*, *beruhigt sein*, En. *rest assured* und spricht von einem *Ruhekissen*. Wenn das Geld dafür wichtig ist, muss es natürlich zuvor angespart werden, ja. Manch einer schläft mit der Waffe unter dem Kopfkissen, andere schlafen mit Kuscheltieren. Geld hat sicher auch eine beruhigende Wirkung.

*sparen* bedeuted wortwörtlich etwas *zur Seite legen*, *in Ruhe lassen*, vgl. En. *spare*.

Ersparte *Einlagen* heißen etwa *Polster* (vgl. En. *bolster up*? En. *bolt* "Bolzen", daher *eine Stange Geld*?).

Erspartes heißt auch *Puffer*, En. *buffer*, von einer mittelalterlichen Bedeutung *pusten, plustern, blasen*. In technischen Anwendungen bezeichnet *Puffer* Vorrichtung zum abfedern von Stößen, oftmals realisiert mit Kissen; vgl. auch *abfedern, Federkissen*. En. *puff*; Italienisch *buffare* ist verwandt, ebenso *buffo*, das kann aber "Schulden" bedeuten. Dessen weitere Herkunft ist unbekannt. Vergleicht man *buffoon*, das ebenso dazu gezählt wird, mit *bluff*, erschließt sich jedoch ein zusammenhang. So ist *bluff* nah an *blow*, was deutlicher wird, wenn *blöffen* hinzugezogen wird, das einerseits als "prahlen" gedeutet wird, was mit "prallen" verglichen wird; Vgl. daher technisch *Puffer*, *Aufprallschutz*; sowie *prall*, etwa bzgl. eines prall aufgeblasenen Ballons; Ein Prahlhans wird eben auch als *aufgeblasen* bezeichnet. Dazu zählt sicher auch *verblüfft*; vgl. dazu En. *blown away*. Demzufolge lassen *blasen*, En. *blow* zumindest die IE Wurzel *bʰleh₁- "to swell, blow up" (auch bleat "blöken [wie ein Schaf]") erkennen, die stark an *bʰel- "to bloom" (auch *Blüte, Blume, flower*) im Sinne von *anwachsen* erinnern, welches eventuel mit "Blut" zusammen hängt (das ist aber ungeklärt). Schon in der Bedeutung *anschwellen, gedeihen* würde *sparen* hierher passen, doch zumindest in der Bedeutung *Absicherung*. In der Wirtschaft kann so eine *Blase* auch mal platzen.

Ferner wird auch *to flow* "fließen" auf ein *bʰleh₃- "to thrive, bloom" (vgl. oben *bloom*) reduziert. Wer erspartes hat, gilt als *flüssig* oder *liquide*. Eventuel gehört das auch hierher.

*Kissen* ist verwandt mit En. *cushion*, beide wohl von Lat. *coxa*. Das erinnert an *cash*, vgl. *Kasse*, doch der Vergleich ist schwierig. Zu zeigen wäre, ob *Kissen* zumindest in der Redewendung auf die *Kasse* zurückgeht (in sofern "im Kissen", nicht "unter dem"). Hier ein vermutliches Wortspiel wieder zu entdecken würde aber zu weit führen.

Comment: Einen etymologischen Zusammenhang zwischen *cash* und *cushion/Kissen* herzustellen ist mutig. Hast Du dafür irgendeine seriöse Referenz, oder ist das nur so Deine eigene Vermutung?